# Java GUI Components online data fetching

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a problem  using `java swing gui` components, My Code fetches online data from MYSQL database, but its taking too much time to display GUI components like textfields that have data.

Comment: Sounds like you are fetching your data from the database within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread...check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  This is of course entirly a guess, for better answers, you might consider supplying a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: use jtable in that for fetching data from the database.

Comment: @simmant Using `JTable` won't help in this situation

Comment: agree with mad programmer the implementation should be some form of swing work thread. you could then post the results as they come available to some Jcomponent like a jtable, best to get a good solid implementation first.

Comment: i got it, I declared connection variable as a global one, i am passing that single connection variable to different sql commands that proram need to execute... Even though your answers helped me a lot to do GUI coding in advanced way..thank you